# mysql insert from select query returning syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I run an online imageboard and I am updating to a newer imageboard software. Rather than manually enter the board information for each new imageboard, I wanted to just port over the fields I need from the old table to the new one, but PHPMYADMIN is giving me a mysql syntax error and I don't know what the problem is:

```
INSERT INTO `tryboards` (uri, title)
SELECT name, desc FROM `aasboards`;
```

This should move the data from the old table to the new, yes? The aasboards table has several columns I want to omit. The tryboards table contains 3 fields, the 3rd one being subtitle, which is nullable and shouldn't be needed for this query.

EDIT: the error is as follows:

> Error

SQL query: Documentation

INSERT INTO `tryboards` ( uri, title )
SELECT name, DESC
FROM `aasboards`

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc FROM `aasboards`' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserved word:

```
INSERT INTO `tryboards` (uri, title)
    SELECT name, `desc` FROM `aasboards`;
```

Comment: That worked. I never considered that it would look at it that way.

Comment: @user3175451 . . . That is what reserved words mean.  And `desc` is not a mysterious one, because it is part of the basic SQL language.